# Unable to script the "add a dock space" function due to conflicts with running as root

Tags: macos, command-line, dock, zsh, mdm

I am a Jamf admin and need to make the "add a dock space" command line function into an easy to click button for our users. Many of them would be hesitant or not technically savvy enough to open Terminal and manage copy/pasting script into Terminal, but I know they would enjoy this tool for Dock management.

It is an easy to find command-line action on the internet:

`defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '{"tile-type"="spacer-tile";}'; killall Dock`

However, this needs to be run as the local user. Jamf's Self Service tool will always run command line actions or scripts as root user by default, since this is mainly meant to handle system-wide processes.

I have used a guide from the Scripting OSX website, which usually helps resolve scripting issues for macOS, but their suggestion for running a command as the current user is failing to work

https://scriptingosx.com/2020/08/running-a-command-as-another-user/

I am placing this script in front of the "defaults write..." command line action.

```
# usage:
#   runAsUser command arguments...
runAsUser() {  
  if [ "$currentUser" != "loginwindow" ]; then
    launchctl asuser "$uid" sudo -u "$currentUser" "$@"
  else
    echo "no user logged in"
    # uncomment the exit command
    # to make the function exit with an error when no user is logged in
    # exit 1
  fi
}
```

It is especially confusing because the guide uses a command line action for "defaults write com.apple.dock", which is the basis of my command line action, yet this does not work.

Does anyone have an idea why this would be failing, and what to do to resolve? Running this with verbose doesn't reveal anything, as it gives an exit code 0 upon completion.

Comment:  declaring variables??? I knew I forgot something, and that fixed it

Comment: Actually, where are the variables *assigned*?  Those aren’t variables that are assigned by default.  Try issuing the the command (in Terminal) `echo $currentUser $loginwindow` and see what the output is. (Sorry, accidentally deleted my original comment)